# How To: Cancel Web Service Function Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jquery

This might be discussed elsewhere but I can't find it.  I have a .Net Web Service that has a function that loops through a date range and runs calculations and updates records in a database.  If you give this said function a long date range, it can take quite some time to complete.  This being the case, I need a way to stop this function.

Is there a way of making the web service function call run in a identified thread so that I can cancel that thread if need be?  Or am I over or under thinking this?  I am using C# .Net Web Page with jQuery to perform the AJAX calls to the web Service function.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Who is deciding to cancel the thread: the caller, or your web service implementation (based on some timeout presumably)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Cancel() method to your web service that sets a state variable.  Then, simply have your long running operation periodically check this variable and stop if its set (with appropriate protection, of course).

Comment: I cannot believe I simply overlooked your answer due to its simplicity.  BUT, as Occam's razor suggests, the simplest is the best answer.  After looking through the other replies, Tejs's answer suggests cancelling the thread as I referenced in my question, BUT, this could leave uncommitted database transactions lingering. So, I thought about your answer more.  With your method, I set a state (or session) variable with the 'cancel' call and then upon the next iteration of the loop, check that variable, that way, any transaction that is in process gets committed and is not left orphaned.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  Don't worry about the overlooking - this is the next best thing to pair programming;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to web service methods:

1. **StartCalculation(parms)** which spanws a long running operation and returns an ID
2. **CancelCalculation(ID)** which cancels the calculation by terminating the long running operation.

The implementation of the 'long running operation' depends on your service hosts (IIS, Windows Service, etc.).

Comment: This is similar to Adam's recommendation as well.  I initially overlooked these answers due to their simplicity.  But, look at Adam's answer for my comments as to why I chose it.

Comment: The main difference to Adam's answer is that I believe you need to return an ID that identifies the operation, otherwise you cannot support multiple clients. Without an ID you wouldn't know which operation to cancel in case there is more than one running!

Comment: Yes, I have a log table that keeps track of which iteration is occurring, and I return the id of that iteration and if you click cancel, it passes that id to the cancel function and sets the application variable to that id to cancel and then upon the next iteration, it cancels the one with the id.  thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that. If you're using .NET 4, you can easily cancel a task:

```
 CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
 var processingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
          foreach(var item in StuffToProcess())
          {
               cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

               // Do your processing in a loop
          }
    });

  var cancelTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
           Thread.Sleep(/* The time you want to allow before cancelling your processing */);
           cts.Cancel();
      });

   try
   {
       Task.WaitAll(processingTask, cancelTask);
   }
   catch(AggregateException ae)
   {
       ae.Flatten().Handle(x =>
          {
               if(x is OperationCanceledException)
               {
                   // Do Anything you need to do when the task was canceled.
                   return true;
               }

               // return false on any unhandled exceptions, true for handled ones
          });
   }
```

Comment: this looks close to what I would want but have the requirement that the user will have the ability to view a queue of requests to this function and cancel specific ones.  there could be 1-20 of these requests going at one time and I need to be able to cancel a specific one.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to keep around a reference to that object in some kind of shared holder instead of firing off a task for it, and then your web manager to elect to call `cts.Cancel()` on a specified token.

Comment: I already keep track of a queue object (just an entry in the db that keeps track of who requested to sync what date range).  So, how do I capture the token for that thread so I can add that to my DB and do I use the code above to cancel that thread?